# Meaning of $x_c$ and $\hat x_c$ in proof of Hammersley–Clifford theorem

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, notation

I'm reading this paper http://image.diku.dk/igel/paper/AItRBM-proof.pdf and I got stuck in page 4 with equation (1) that's based on Hammersley–Clifford theorem. I'm not good in reading set theory notation and also I wasn't able to understand the point from the equation.

I couldn't understand what are $x_c$ and $\hat{x}_c$

Here's the section, I'm stuck just at equation (1):

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\mathbf x$ and $\hat{\mathbf x}$ are vectors indexed by the vertex set $V$. The assumption in (1) is that every entry of $\mathbf x$ and $\hat{\mathbf x}$ corresponding to some vertex in the clique $C$ coïncide.

Example: if $V=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $C=\{1,2\}$, condition (1) asks that some function $g$ on $\Lambda^5$ is such that $g(x,y,z,t,u)=g(x,y,z',t',u')$ for every $x$, $y$, $z$, $t$, $u$, $z'$, $t'$, $u'$ in $\Lambda$.

Comment: I'm still thinking about it actually and I'm a bit confused. I think my problem has to do with understanding what indexing by a set is and what is a family. I will read more about that and then I might ask you here again. I'm very thankful because I've been stuck for 3 days now. I have a tiny question please: $x$ and $\hat{x}$ are vectors of size $|V|$, right?

Comment: hmmm could like please read (1) in plain English? Something like "for every two vectors $x$ and $\hat{x}$ of values of the state space where each vector has a size of the same number of vertices, then...etc" something like that :) that would be extremely generous :)

Comment: So after reading about families what I understood is that the left hand side of the equal sign is a family and the right hand side is also a family, and if those families are the same then the functions give the same value for the two vectors $x$ and $\hat{x}$. Yet what is confusing for me is the idea of the equality of the families. Because for me it looks that both families are identical already and I'm unable to see how they relate to $x$ and $\hat{x}$ :(

Comment: Added an example.

Comment: oh so basically we are talking about a particular clique here! So "given that the two vectors elements coincide for a particular clique, then $g(x) = g(\hat{x})$"